# Temporary License Play Store

Tags: android, app-store, payment, temporary, android-lvl

I would like to release a paid application soon and put it on Google Play Store for purchase.
Regarding licensing I have seen that Google offers the License Verification Library (LVL) which is great and the documentation is also very useful.
My only problem is that I would need the option of a temporary license, so:

- if a user buys the app on the Play Store for a small amount of money he should be able to run it for a certain period of time after the first start.
- after expiration the user should be able to purchase the license again from the Google Play Store and run it on the same device with the same account again.

I am looking for a license renewal option offered by Google without me having to setup my own licensing server.
It appears to me that this is not possible with Google Play Store since once an application is bought it is registered at Google and the user does not need re-purchase it no matter what device he is using.

My application is intended to be used for business purposes and therefore I am looking for a licensing model that Google supports. Up to now I was not able to find anything on temporary licensing with LVLs. Are there other possibilities you know of that I could implement? I am really looking for an option on the Play Store since it is used widely.

Comment: they have in app billing...Why not just set up your licence purchases with that? they buy a new "token" from within the app whenever theirs runs out. And the app checks for fresh tokens before launching.

Comment: This question is not about programming, it's about what license option from google should I use so it's more a legal advice question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Using LVL for this is a bad idea because:

- It really isn't meant for a subscription type model
- It is very easy to crack. Most implementations can be cracked by scripts like AntiLVL

Instead, you could use the [Subscriptions](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html#billing-types) feature of the In App purchase API provided by Google. This is specially designed to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. In-app billing seems to be very useful for what I have planned, I have already installed the sample application provided on the SDK and gone through the code but it is very extensive I need more time to think it through.

Whenever the user buys a "token" it will be stored locally - so if the user deletes his app data he will also loose his "token" or license to run the app. I would think that this is a problem I could live with but if you know of any another approach please let me know.

Thanks again!

Comment: If the user has bought it once, and it is a managed item, then whenever he/she reinstalls the app you can use the restore transactions feature to find out if the user has bought said token or not.